# Is there a usable Amiga CD32 Emulator?

Tags: emulation, amiga, commodore

I know that UAE is a pretty good Amiga Emulator, but it seems aimed to emulatr an Amiga 500 or a 1200. While the CD32 is similar to the Amiga 1200 - 68EC020 CPU, 2 MB ChipRAM, AGA - it has a special Chip, the [Akiko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akiko_(Amiga)), which does not seem to be supported by UAE.

[Amiga Forever lists](http://www.amigaforever.com/features/) CD32 Support, but it is not stated if that just means supplying the KickStart ROMs or if it actually includes Akiko Emulation. As it's commercial, I can't just try it out before.

Also, there is [Airsoft's Akiko](http://www.airsoftsoftwair.de/en/prod_akiko.html), which was last updated in 2002. Sure, there is always a point where one is "done" writing an emulator, but I still wonder if this is any good and even compatible with newer systems? It looks also only his UAE Modifications are Open Source, while the Akiko-part is not part of that.

Comment: That would be cool to have!  I miss my Amiga 2000 with GVP 040 board/16 Meg RAM, etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Amiga Forever 2010](http://www.amigaforever.com/whatsnew/) just added CD32 Emulation. Tried it with a few Games and it seems to work fine. I tried Microcosm and it runs perfectly as well.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have any Amiga CD32 programs to try it on, but [WinUAE](http://www.winuae.net/) *seems* to have CD32 support.  The documentation is a little sketchy, but the "bugs fixed" list has a whole bunch of CD32 references in it.  And the most recent release was a month ago.

Also, despite not being all that active, I've seen it claimed that Akkiko will run 80%+ of all CD32 software.

Answer (score 1):

[FS-UAE](https://fs-uae.net/) is another alternative amiga emulator that supports CD32. The interface is simpler to navigate if your main focus is playing games and it is cross platform (Windows, MacOS, Linux)

You still require Amiga Kickstart ROMS to run FS-UAE but it can import them from Amiga Forever if you have that installed already.